# How to protect from resubmiting action

Tags: php, sql, forms, get, action

I get variables with GET and have link like:

```
.../cart.php?article=dress&color=red&qty=1&price=100&action=add
```

The form redirect to same .php file and have:

```
if(isset($_GET["action"]))  
        {  
        switch($_GET["action"])  
                {  
        case "add":  
                ......  
                break;  
                }  
         }
```

How to remove action from link or some other way protect to resubmit action. No need to be removed others variables because under the form have list of articles and when click back is good to be see what have in the list.

Comment: Why not using POST and the PRG pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for your form ?

Comment: I don't know, did it help. I was thinking that with POST also have same problem.

Comment: I have several actions from one form did the post will help me?

Comment: If the `action` variable is a POST variable, it won't be part of the URL, therefore, when redirecting after your post, you will not be able to resubmit it.

Comment: I try with POST but is the same, only that browser ask to confirm resubmitting. A lot of users will click confirm without knowing that will add another article.

Comment: Unless you implement the PRG pattern that I mentionned earlier. It's called POST/Redirect/GET, because it forces the user to be redirected to a page that hasn't been reached by a POST, so refreshing the page doesn't cause a resubmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($_GET['action']);
header("Location: cart.php?" . http_build_query($_GET));
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly:
If I use POST the form will not resubmit, but the user will not see the list of already added articles under the form when click back.

Barmar I have to put unset at bottom of all my pages to be sure that always be unset actions, or put it in the case?